# decorator in python 2 that decorate given method of given class

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-2.x

I have given arbitraly class `A` with method `m` and I would like to create decorator that can be added to new function `f` and this decorator will allow to execute `f` every time that `m` is called but to execute `f` before `m` and `f` should intercept arguments of `m`

I need help defining `pre_execution` decorator - I have something but it's not working and I can't figure out how to make it work

```py
#a.py
class A:
    def m(self, x):
        return x+1
```

```py
#mydecorator.py     -- need help with code in this file
def pre_execution(klass, method):
    old_fn = getattr(klass, method)

    def inner(fn, *args):
        # @wraps(fn)
        def iin(*args, **kwargs):
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
            return old_fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return iin
    setattr(klass, method, inner)
    return inner
```

```py
# main.py
from a import A
from mydecorator import pre_execution

if __name__ == "__main__":
    @pre_execution(A, 'm')
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        print "in"
        print "my code using args and kwargs"
        print "out"

    a = A()
    print a.m(1) == 2
    print a.m(1)
```

expected output:

```
in
my code using args and kwargs
out
True
```

Comment: Decorating `f` only wraps calls to `f`.  If you want to change the behavior of `m` you will have to monkey-patch it inside of `f`'s decorator.

Comment: Shouldn't your expected output call `f` twice (once for each call to `a.m`)? Or do you only want `f` to execute when `a` is created?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @chepner thank you for remark - I have made corrections in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
def pre_execution(klass, method):
    old_method = getattr(klass, method)

    def patch_klass(f):
        def new_method(*args, **kwargs):
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            return old_method(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(klass, method, new_method)
        return f
    return patch_klass
```

`pre_execution` saves a reference to the original method, then defines a function that will be returned and called on `f`. This function defines a *new* method that calls `f` before calling the original method. `patch_klass` then replaces the old method with the new in. It also returns the original function unmodified, in case you want to use `f` elsewhere.

```
$ python tmp.py
in
my code using args and kwargs
out
True
in
my code using args and kwargs
out
2
```

Note that this works in Python 2 or 3.